# (Django) include does not import other apps' urls

Tags: django, url, include

In my Django project I have 2 apps: core and books. In my **core/urls.py**, I use `python include('books.url')` to import the urls from **books/urls.py**, but I keep getting this error

[image]

I have been having this issue now that's bugging me. I had a workaround for it, though I really want to fix this.

**core/urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
# local

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include('books.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**books/urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
# local
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from books.schema import schema

urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql/', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema)), 
]
```

As suggested by SO, I have:

1. put books.urls inside the single quotes ' '
2. placed the `path('/', include('books.urls'))` on top
3. switch from `from django.urls import include` to
   `from django.conf.urls import include`

The only workaround I have is place all urls into the **core/urls.py**, but that seems too chunky in the long run. I don't get why `include` works for everyone but not me!

Could you help me with this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Now `GraphQLView` is called with the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/`, if you want to call it with the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/`, you need to change your code:

**core/urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
# local

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include('books.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**books/urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
# local
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from books.schema import schema

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema)), 
]
```